# Auto-click with javascript/jquery onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if it is possible for jquery or javascript with some code
to make the "click" event click on some dimensions of the website which is fully loaded on chrome.

Lets say that i want the javascript/jquery code to click only the

x:250px y:300px   on the website.

Is it possible???

What im trying to say is that when i run a code i want to "real-click" aka NATIVE-CLICK. lets say an image but i want to set the cordinates, not the class or id of that image.